# Aggregating data with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Let's use the `mpg` dataset as an example, specifically the `class` and `cyl` columns. I can see how many entries are there, per single `class`, and differentiate the fill color based on the cyl value:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg)
p <- p + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=class, fill=factor(cyl)), position=position_dodge())
print(p)
```

[image]

What I'd like to see, though, is the **average** count of entries (per `class`), per different values of `cyl`. Basically, if you look at the plot above, I want a single bar per class, whose height should be the average height of the colored bars for that class.

I am able to get this result by preprocessing the data frame, e.g.:

```
df <- aggregate(formula=cyl~class, data=mpg, FUN=function(x) { length(x) / length(unique(x)) })
p <- ggplot(df)
p <- p + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=class, y=cyl), stat='identity')
p <- p + ylab('average count')
```

That gives my **desired output**:

[image]

However, given how powerful ggplot2 is, I am wondering if this is possible through ggplot functions. I guess this involves using a specific `stat` (maybe with `group=cyl`?), but I am not able to.

Comment: Give a look at `stat_summary` [link](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html)

Comment: @user3631369 I am playing with it right now, but I am not getting results. I can't aggregate over the cyl field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can plug your formula straight into `stat_summary()` to generate the desired result without intermediate steps:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg) + 
  stat_summary(aes(x = class, y = cyl), 
               fun.y = function(x) length(x) / length(unique(x)), 
               geom = "bar")
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to pass `fun.y` an aggregation function, that is based on other variables in the data.frame? (So, that I can compute a sum within each group - somehow I couldn't get this to work...)

Comment: Could u give an example? Perhaps ask a new questions